# Download link not working on server

Tags: url, laravel-4, download

I am trying to add a download link to a file on my page, the file can either be a Microsoft Word document, a PDF file, or zip file or some other kind of document, i have the path to the file stored in my database, my issue is it works on my localhost but on the server I get: **NotFoundHttpException**

This is how the link is generated:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to($row->file_url) }}" class="widget-control-right"><span class="fa fa-download"></span></a>
```

This is how the file url looks like:

```
'uploads/data/library/G7TkXMdk7BAB12Cn//Guide.pdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your problem, try to use helper function that is called `link_to_asset`.

```
{{ link_to_asset($row->file_url, "Download", array("class" => "widget-control-right")) }}
```

But the better approach is here :

```
<a href="{{ route('file.download', $row->id) }}" class="widget-control-right"><span class="fa fa-download"></span></a>
```

In your route.php

```
Route::get("file/download/{id}", array("as" => "file.download", function ($id) {
    $row = Model::find($id);
    return Response::download($row->file_url);
}));
```

Hope it will be useful for you.